# Dual Australian/UK citizen entering Australia on UK passport

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, australia, dual-nationality

I am off to the UK on Thursday and have just noticed that my Australian passport only has 5 months left on it. I can travel out on my UK passport and come back in on the UK one with the Australian one there as proof of citizenship. Should I do the same with my son who is travelling with me or would he be best to use his Australian passport both ways. He's not feeling happy about being separated from me if we have to go through different passport controls, especially if I get taken to the side for checks.

Comment: Always use the same line as the others in your party if at all possible. It is fairly likely that you can/should use the Australians lines even when traveling to Australia on your UK passport.

Comment: If you wish to enter the UK on an Australian passport it need only be valid for the length of your intended stay (not six months). If your son is under 16 the UK Home Office strongly prefers that you and your son stay together at the passports desk---they don't care whether you both use the EU or the non-EU line but you should stay together. This is a recent anti-child-smuggling rule. To re-enter Australia your Australian passport needs only to be valid on arrival. Australia (apparently) requires that dual nationals enter on their Australian passport.

Answer (score 6):

You should enter the UK on the British passport and Australia on the Aussie one. Absolutely no need to show both anywhere.

No country on Earth requires their own passports to be valid beyond the arrival date, and many will even accept expired ones. [Australia belongs to the former category.](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=au&DE=au&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX)